# How to change the value of second level variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, variables, pointers

Let's consider 2 variables in bash as following:

```
X = 8  
Y = X
```

If I want to print the value of `X` using the variable `Y` I could do `echo ${!Y}` and the value `8` will be printed

Now the question is, how can I change the value of `X` using the variable `Y` ?

Answer (score 7):

By using `eval`:

```
$ X=8
$ Y=X
$ echo ${!Y}
8
$ eval $Y=3
$ echo $X
3
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
X=8; Y=X; echo ${!Y}
8
echo $(($Y=3))
3
echo $X
3
(($Y=7)); echo $X
7
```

Here's a couple more ways:

```
let $Y=4; echo $X
4
_[$Y=6]=1; echo $X
6
```

Comment: Nice … any more ways of doing it .. +1